# NFS mounted share read/write too slow

Tags: io, debian, nfs

I have several NFS shares mounted as source folders and several as destination ones.
File is taken from source, and with some changes put to destination.
Making changes itself takes very short time,  but read/write operations from/to NFS shares take extremely  long time, e.g. 10MB are transferred for around 6 mins.
Any ideas how to speed this process up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I'm on RHEL/EC2. And experiencing the NFS is so slow. Not sure why :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On client tweaking NFS mount options might significantly improve performance.
I found that default `rsize` and `wsize` are too big and reducing their values helps. However testing would be the best way to determine optimal values for `rsize` and `wsize` in your environment. At the moment on gigabit network I'm using `rsie=262144,wsize=262144` but this may not be ideal for you. Also `noatime,nodiratime` may help a little.

Comment: Also on server increasing number of RPCNFSDCOUNT might help. On [Debian](http://debian.org) it can be found in `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server`.